# How to ask Mathematica to fill in colors between curves in the given code?

Tags: plotting, color, filling

I am using this code

```
x = {-2, -1.5, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2};
y = {1.21, 1.24, 1.26, 1.21, 1.28, 1.25, 1.21, 1.23, 1.26};

p1 = ListPlot[Thread[{x, y}], PlotStyle -> Red, Joined -> True];
p2 = ListPlot[Thread[{x, y^2}], PlotStyle -> Red, Joined -> True];
p3 = ListPlot[Thread[{x, y^3}], PlotStyle -> Blue, Joined -> True];
p4 = ListPlot[Thread[{x, y^4}], PlotStyle -> Blue, Joined -> True];
Show[p1, p2, p3, p4, PlotRange -> All]
```

and the result is plot no.1. How can I ask Mathematica to fill in colors between the curves as plot no.2?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ListPlot[
 {Thread[{x, y}], Thread[{x, y^2}],
  Thread[{x, y^3}], Thread[{x, y^4}]},
 Filling -> {
   1 -> {{2}, Opacity[0.3, Red]}, 
   3 -> {{4}, Opacity[0.3, Blue]}
 },
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Red, Blue, Blue}, Joined -> True,
 PlotRange -> {1, 3}
]
```

[image: plot with colors]

Comment: +1 More compactly, `ListPlot[Thread[{x, y^#}] & /@ Range[4], ...]`

Answer (score 4):

You can also construct a  [`TemporalData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemporalData.html) object from your `x` and `y` and use it with `ListLinePlot`:

```
td = TemporalData[Table[y^i, {i, 4}], {x}];

llp = ListLinePlot[td,
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Red, RGBColor[.45, .77, .92], RGBColor[.45, .77, .92]}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}, 3 -> {4}}, 
 PlotRange -> {1, All}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `Table[y^i, {i, 4}]` as input data and add the option `DataRange -> MinMax[x]`:

```
llp = ListLinePlot[Table[y^i, {i, 4}], 
 DataRange -> MinMax[x],
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Red, RGBColor[.45, .77, .92], RGBColor[.45, .77, .92]}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}, 3 -> {4}}, 
 PlotRange -> {1, All}]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
Normal[llp] /. p_Polygon :> Dynamic[texturedPoly[CurrentValue["Color"]][p]]
```

[image]

where

```
ClearAll[texturedPoly]
texturedPoly[color_: Red, thickness_: 10, n_: 200, sd_: 100, jitter_: 5][p_Polygon] := 
 Module[{BSF = BSplineFunction[Join @@ (RandomSample[Partition[#, 20]] & @ 
   SortBy[RandomPoint[BoundingRegion[p[[1]], "MinConvexPolygon"], n], First])]}, 
  {Opacity[.8], Texture @ 
   ImageEffect[Graphics[{CapForm["Round"], JoinForm["Round"], 
      color, AbsoluteThickness[thickness], 
      Line[BSF /@ Subdivide[sd]]}], {"Jitter", jitter}], 
   Polygon[p[[1]], VertexTextureCoordinates -> Automatic]}]
```